# Install ESXi using Intel AMT

Tags: esxi, intel-amt, vpro

I tried installing ESXi 4.1 U1 latest build using Intel AMT (Intel DQ67SW mainboard with added Intel Gbit NIC and Dell SAS 5i HBA). I know that ESXi is running on the system and the HDDs are detected, that's not the problem, it's a problem with the remote install using Intel AMT: ESXi claims it can't find the CD (please see the linked screenshot below). Any idea if there is an AMT setting relevant to this? I could install Windows 7 using Intel AMT without any problems, but ESXi doesn't work ):

BTW for Intel AMT I am using VNCViewer Plus, latest edition.

I already wanted to contact Intel, but after I have selected my mainboard I just get a message teling me, that the mainboard isn't supported by intel through e-mail...

Here is a screenshot of the error message: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/sjjr6bpk/esxi.png

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i was too much focused on intel amt - it's an esxi problem: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/276393?start=30&tstart=0